# How to tell webhosting company which has their own servers from a reseller?

Tags: web-hosting, reseller

As question is straightforward, is there any tools that let you know if a web hosting company is running its own servers infrastructure.

Answer (score 1):

I hope, your question is, "How do we know is it a reseller hosting company or hosting company with their own servers? "

There is one way to find out, You can find out using the hostname of the server.

Most of the hosting companies will have a pattern in naming the servers. For example, example will have a hostname like serverXX.example.com

So, in this way, You can find out. There will be a naming pattern.

Comment: you mean there are two patterns, one for each type of webhosting provider, how to find out from this naming pattern ?